# JSF 2.0 Custom Exception Handler - ViewHandler is not redirecting in Weld Application

Tags: java, jsf-2, viewexpiredexception

I use the by [Ed Burns suggested custom exception handler](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2) to display an error page whenever a specific exception occurs. I also try do display an error page when the context is not active.
However, this part (line 45./46.) causes trouble:

```
nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "viewExpired");
fc.renderResponse();
```

Here comes the full CustomExceptionHandler (configured correctly as Ed Burns suggests in his Blog)

```
package com.sun.faces;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext;

public class ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

public ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
    this.wrapped = wrapped;
}

@Override
public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
    return this.wrapped;
}

@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
        Throwable t = context.getException();
        if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            ViewExpiredException vee = (ViewExpiredException) t;
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            NavigationHandler nav =
                    fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            try {
                // Push some useful stuff to the request scope for
                // use in the page
                requestMap.put("currentViewId", vee.getViewId());

                nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "viewExpired");
                fc.renderResponse();

            } finally {
                i.remove();
            }
        }
    if (t instanceof ContextNotActiveException) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            NavigationHandler nav =
                    fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

         try {
                nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "contextNotActive");
                fc.renderResponse();

         } finally {
         i.remove();
     }
     }
    }
    // At this point, the queue will not contain any exceptions I want to handle (for now).
    // Therefore, let the parent handle them.
    getWrapped().handle();

    }
}
```

However I always get a "view could not be rendered" print-out in the console. So why is it not rendering that error page. I assume it is caused by the not active context (which is used by the NavigationHandler)!

**Can anyone confirm this behavior?**

P.S.: I am using Weld 1.1 with Mojarra 2.0.4

Comment: and you have the viewExpired.xhtml ?

Comment: Are you using JSTL in the pages? I found that I had an NPE occurring because I was trying to read information in the CDI bean which was set in a PhaseListener. However, when the page was being loaded, the CDI bean was instantiated first and threw the NPE because JSTL is out of phase with JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got to add a navigation rule into your faces-config.xml file, something like this:

```
 <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>contextNotActive</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/contextNotActive.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
```